# Does saveChanges method of ObjectContext is wrapped in transaction?

Tags: entity-framework

Does anybody know if the saveChanges method sends the SQL script that is wrapped into transaction?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will send the SQL to the database. But you need to commit the changes for them to be saved, otherwise they will be lost when the transaction timesout.

Comment: "Commit changes" - you mean to call "saveChanges" method, right?

Comment: No, if you use a transaction, you must first savechanges on your data, then commit on the transaction